# Which permissions are required for a technical Terraform user in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I like to run my terraform scripts as a technical user in the AWS-cloud - but `terraform init` returns a `Error refreshing state: AccessDenied`.

Here is what I did: I created a user in AWS (IAM) and gave it the "AdministratorAccess" and "AmazonS3FullAccess" privilege, saved the `ACCESS_KEY` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`and put those as env-valiables in my local console

```
   set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=..
   set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
```

For more infos I set the `DEBUG` flag in terraform, too

```
    set TF_LOG=DEBUG
```

then

```
    terraform init
```

results in a successful first `POST` to `sts/GetCallerIdentity`:

```
<SNIP>
2021-07-26T09:14:10.232+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: sts.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.37.0 (go1.16.4; windows; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.0.3
Content-Length: 43
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<SNIP>/20210726/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=<SNIP>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20210726T071410Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
-----------------------------------------------------
2021-07-26T09:14:10.971+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 416
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 07:14:10 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: <SNIP>
```

But the next `GET` to `s3/ListObjects` is `403 - Forbidden`

```
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
GET /?max-keys=1000&prefix=env%3A%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: <SNIP>.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.37.0 (go1.16.4; windows; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.0.3
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<SNIP>/20210726/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<SNIP>
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: <SNIP>
X-Amz-Date: 20210726T071410Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip


-----------------------------------------------------
2021-07-26T09:14:11.054+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 07:14:10 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Bucket-Region: eu-central-1
X-Amz-Id-2: <SNIP>
X-Amz-Request-Id: <SNIP>
```

I explain that as suficcient access rights for log-in but not for more. Strange thing: the "AmazonS3FullAccess" explicitly allows `ListObjects`...

I found no info about the required rights in the docs - can you help?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your suggestions, you pointed me in the right direction:
Turned out I was trying to access a S3 bucket that was created under a different AWS account than the IAM tech user. Unfortunately you cannot create the same S3 bucket name again in a different accout. So I had to create a different one with another name. Next I had to change the `bucket` var in my script depending on target system. I learned that you cannot pass variables in the `terraform / backend` section of your `.tf` files... Took me some time to find out that you can change the S3 bucket via a CLI parameter:

```
terraform init -backend-config="bucket=..."
```

Hope someone finds this useful - cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify what is a "technical" user?

Comment: Just another user that is not used for GUI login but for tech calls

Comment: Well, it needs access to the s3 bucket containing its state, and access to the dynamodb containing the corresponding locks. And then it needs full access to basically all services and resources you want it to manage.

Comment: Chances are you configurations are wrong, the access keys point to different accounts or the bucket is located in another account, or encrytped with a KMS key in a different account, or ...

Comment: can you paste your backend configuration block and S3 policy?